# How to add multiple years to DateTimeIndex in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetimeindex

I'd like to add multiple years to my date index in pandas, but have not been able to do so:

ts is a dataframe with a series and relevant dates. I would like to extend those dates by an additional several years in order to add other series for plotting/analysis.

ts.head()

```
date
2014-12-31         NaN
2015-12-31    0.617876
2016-12-31    0.472640
2017-12-31    0.426240
2018-12-31    0.297176
Name: BL-US, dtype: float64
```

I've tried

```
ts.index.union([ts.index[-1] + datetime.timedelta(years=x) for x in range(7)])
```

and received the following error:

TypeError: 'years' is an invalid keyword argument for **new**()

Any suggestions? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`date_range`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.date_range.html):

```
ts.index.union(pd.date_range(ts.index[-1], periods=5, freq='Y'))
```

output:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2014-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2016-12-31', '2017-12-31',
               '2018-12-31', '2019-12-31', '2020-12-31', '2021-12-31',
               '2022-12-31'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='A-DEC')
```

Answer (score 0):

This possibly works:

```py
ts.index.union([ts.index[-1] + pd.offsets.DateOffset(years=x) for x in range(5)])
```

Comment: See how to [format code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) on stack overflow